# PHP str_replace with pattern from db

Tags: php, database, text, replace, str-replace

I'm going crazy for this...I'm trying to remove some text using a database of strings to be removed. This is my function:

```
function remove($str){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `deltext` ORDER BY `freq` DESC";
    $rslt = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
    while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($rslt)){
        $str=str_replace($row['text'],"",$str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

The text I'm trying to remove is:

```
"&gt;Lavora con noi
&gt;Posizioni Aperte
</p>"
```

The following works fine:

```
$str=str_replace("&gt;Lavora con noi
&gt;Posizioni Aperte
</p>","Paperino",$str);
```

But if I try to use the database, it won't work, someone know why?

Thanks
Valerio

Answer (score 0):

you can use REPLACE function, just remove the * from your query and fetch what you need only like

```
SELECT REPLACE(deltext.text_name, "_", " ") FROM `deltext` ORDER BY `freq` DESC
```

also your query is not well written, why you are updating $str everytime, i think you should use $str as an array.

also you can try this

```
str_replace(html_entity_decode('&ndash;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '', $string);
```

Comment: It is good to know but I can't use REPLACE because the text I need to modify is not on the database